# How to get the last updated row in a table inside a Join query (Laravel 5)

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel-5.1

I have query like this one:

```
$deals=DB::table('leadsheet')
            ->join('Deal', 'leadsheet.leadcode', '=', 'Deal.leadcode')
            ->join('vipbooking', function ($join) {
                        $join->on('leadsheet.leadcode', '=', 'vipbooking.leadcode')
                         ->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(`id`) from vipbooking)"));
            })
            ->where('leadsheet.leadcat', '=','Delegates')
            ->get();
```

I am getting following error:

```
Missing argument 3 for Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::where(),
```

it is pointing to the following line:

```
->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(`id`) from vipbooking)"));
```

I want to get the max ID from vipbooking form.

For example.

Leadsheet

```
id | leadcode | leadcat

1  | DL2016012| Delegates
2  | DL2016013| Delegates
3  | VL2016001| Vendors
4  | VL2016002| Vendors
```

Deals

```
id | leadcode | DealAmount

1  | DL2016012| 123
2  | VL2016002| 1000
```

vipbooking

```
    id | leadcode | date      | bookingtxt

    1  | DL2016012| 20-04-2016| xxx
    2  | DL2016012| 20-04-2016| dddd
    3  | VL2016012| 21-04-2016| ppp
```

So from above example I am trying to get the booking form details which was filled recently by the Delegate.

So my Out put should have:

```
 2 123 | Delegates| DL2016012| 20-04-2016| dddd
```

Thanks

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with solving the problem in mysql , and then figure out how to reverse engineer that into laravel-speak. For assistance in constructing the query in MySQL, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry okay I am working on it . Basically I am trying to get the last vipbooking form filled by a Delegate (User) , Here Lead has One to One relationship between deal and Leadsheet. I should get the last booking form filled by all the delegates who has Deal in the Deal table

Comment: @Strawberry Please have a look on my Example tables

Comment: Feel free to disregard my advice - but,personally, I'm not prepared to take this further without those steps being addressed.

Comment: @Strawberry I have implemented the step 2 that you asked for , Can you explain step 1 please what exactly can I produce to make the question easily understandable

Comment: I'm not sure that using `DB::raw` in the `where` will have the result you expect, try using ``whereRaw("id = (select max(`id`) from vipbooking)")``

Answer (score 0):

```
->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(`id`) from vipbooking)"));
```

The error is asking you for a third parameter, so change that line into this:

```
->where('vipbooking.id','=', DB::raw("(select max(`id`) from vipbooking)"));
```

Alternatively you could use another 'on' more:

```
$join->on('leadsheet.leadcode', '=', 'vipbooking.leadcode')
     ->on('vipbooking.id', '=', DB::raw("(select max(`id`) from vipbooking)"));
```